# AWS Lambda not working when deployed with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a lambda using AWS CDK and it seems not to be working/deployed properly.
The "box" in the pipeline is green, so no errors are returned.

Everything appears to be fine, but when I ran it manually to test, I receive the next message:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "Could not find the required 'QuickSight.Lambdas.SpiceRefresh.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."
}
```

The issue is that if I download the artefact manually to my machine, and upload it with the `Function package` upload button, it is working properly.

I have one `Stack` which contains `CfnParametersCode` which is the stack I use to create the lambda.

```
public class LambdaStack : Stack
{

    public CfnParametersCode LambdaCode { get; set; }

    //code

    private Function BuildSpiceRefreshLambda()
    {
        LambdaCode = Code.FromCfnParameters();

        var func = new Function(this, Constants.Lambda.LambdaName, new FunctionProps
        {
            Code = LambdaCode,
            Handler = Constants.Lambda.LambdaHandler,
            FunctionName = Constants.Lambda.LambdaName,
            MemorySize = 1024,
            Tracing = Tracing.ACTIVE,
            Timeout = Duration.Seconds(480),
            Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_CORE_2_1,
            Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"ENVIRONMENT", Fn.Ref(Constants.EnvironmentVariables.Environment)},
                {"APPLICATION_NAME", Constants.Lambda.ApplicationName},
                {"AWS_ACCOUNT_ID", Fn.Ref("AWS::AccountId")},
                {"LOG_GROUP_NAME", Constants.Lambda.LogGroupName}
            },
            ReservedConcurrentExecutions = 1,
            Role = SpiceRefreshLambdaRole,
            Vpc = this.GetProjectVpc(),
            SecurityGroups = new ISecurityGroup[]
            {
                securityGroup
            }
        });
        return func;
    }
}
```

and then I have the pipeline which one of the steps is build the lambda:

```
var lambdaBuild = new PipelineProject(this, "appLambda", new PipelineProjectProps
{
    BuildSpec = BuildSpec.FromObject(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["version"] = "0.2",
        ["phases"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["install"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["commands"] = new string[]
                {
                    "echo \"Installing lambda tools for dotnet\"",
                    "dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools",
                }
            },
            ["build"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["commands"] = new string[]
                {
                    "echo \"Packaging app lambda\"",
                    "(cd app/src/Lambdas/app.Lambdas.Action; dotnet lambda package)"
                }
            }
        },
        ["artifacts"] = new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            ["files"] = new[]
            {
                "app/src/Lambdas/app.Lambdas.Action/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/app.Lambdas.Action.zip",
            }
        }
    }),
    Environment = new BuildEnvironment
    {
        BuildImage = LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_2_0
    }
});

var lambdaBuildOutput = new Artifact_("LambdaBuildOutput");


new Amazon.CDK.AWS.CodePipeline.Pipeline(this, "appPipeline", new PipelineProps
{
    ArtifactBucket = Bucket.FromBucketAttributes(this, "artifact-bucket", new BucketAttributes
    {
        BucketArn = "bucket",
        EncryptionKey = "key"
    }),
    Role = "role",
    Stages = new[]
    {
        new StageProps
        {
            StageName = "Source",
            Actions = new[]
            {
                new CodeCommitSourceAction(new CodeCommitSourceActionProps
                {
                    ActionName = "Source",
                    Repository = code,
                    Output = sourceOutput,
                })
            }
        },
        new StageProps
        {
            StageName = "Build",
            Actions = new[]
            {
                new CodeBuildAction(new CodeBuildActionProps
                {
                    ActionName = "Lambda_Build",
                    Project = lambdaBuild,
                    Input = sourceOutput,
                    Outputs = new[] {lambdaBuildOutput},
                }),
            }
        },
        new StageProps
        {
            StageName = "Deploy",
            Actions = new[]
            {
                new CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction(new CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackActionProps
                {
                    ActionName = "DeployLambdaapp",
                    TemplatePath = props.appLambdaStack.StackTemplate,
                    StackName = "appLambdaDeploymentStack",
                    AdminPermissions = true,
                    ParameterOverrides = props.appLambdaStack.LambdaCode.Assign(lambdaBuildOutput.S3Location), 
                    ExtraInputs = new[] {lambdaBuildOutput},
                    Role = "role",
                    DeploymentRole = "deployRole"
                }),
            }
        }
    }
});
```

- there is more steps but they are not relevant.

so as you can see I am applying the `ParameterOverrides` to `props.appLambdaStack.LambdaCode.Assign(lambdaBuildOutput.S3Location)` which seems to be fine, because When the lambda gets created, and it specifies the size, which is the same size as the lambda was supposed to be, but when I execute it I receive that `"errorMessage": "Could not find the required 'QuickSight.Lambdas.SpiceRefresh.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."`

On the result Cloudformation file seems to be fine too:

```
 "appLambdaF0BB8286": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "appLambdaSourceBucketNameParameter"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Ref": "appLambdaSourceObjectKeyParameter"
          }
        },
        "Handler": "Constants.Lambda.LambdaHandler",  //same as the constant in c#

        //Rest of the properties
    }
}
```

I checked before creating the post and most of the people had a problem with the handler. Un fortunately if I download manually the object in `appLambdaSourceBucketNameParameter`, `appLambdaSourceObjectKeyParameter` and upload it to the lambda, it works perfectly. I think that will exclude my issue.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The issue is that in the artifact I am returning the lambda `.zip`

```
["files"] = new[]
{
    "app/src/Lambdas/app.Lambdas.Action/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/app.Lambdas.Action.zip",
}
```

But what I really need is to return the binaries of the lambda. (the publish folder)

```
["artifacts"] = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{
    ["base-directory"] = "app/src/Lambdas/app.Lambdas.Action/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish",
    ["files"] = new[] { "**.*" }
}
```

nothing else changed, and it worked.

Cloudformation translation:

before I was exporting `artifact::app.Lambdas.Action.zip`
then AWS was trying to find the binaries. 
Now it is exporting `artifact::**.*`, so all the files.